# How to allow powershell to download an EXE from a .net core MVC web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, asp.net-core

I have a .net core MVC web app that depends on a .net framework console app.  When the Core app builds, so too does the console app and I get the `exe` in the bin directory:

[image]

This is working great, however now I need to provide an endpoint through the web app that allows anyone to download the EXE (the intent is to allow a powershell script to download the exe via an endpoint).

How can this be achieved?

I understand the following can be used to actually download the file:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:8080/download/tokenizer.exe -OutFile c:\download\tokenizer.exe
```

However I don't know how to get the `exe` accessible.  I believe I need to move the EXE from the `bin` to some directory that I then configure as being publicly accessible, but I'm lost on the details here.

Comment: How are you serving the rest of your static content? (`wwwroot`?)

Comment: @SLaks I just checked and yes it's `wwwroot` - I'm a bit new to .net core conventions.  Does that mean I need a post-build event to copy into wwwroot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default ASP.NET Core static files middleware will only serve content types that it understands.  Unknown file types will return a 404.

The middleware can be configured to serve unknown file types, however it is safer to add your own content types explictly:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".exe"] = "application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = provider,            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core applications serve static files from the `wwwroot` directory (you can see this configured in Startup.cs).

To serve a static file, you need to copy it there.

Comment: Is any custom configuration needed to support `GET` with `exe` files?  I know .net framework / web.configs needed some coercing in this situation...

Comment: And - do you know what the best way to copy a file to wwwroot from the `bin` directory would be?

Comment: I don't think .Net Core does any filtering by extensions.  You should use a Post-Build event.

Comment: Right - that's what I'm playing with now.  I'll create another question for this.  Thank you!

Comment: I have the file being copied via `copy /Y $(ProjectDir)bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\tokenizer.exe $(ProjectDir)wwwroot\exe\tokenizer.exe` and see it however navigating to `/exe/tokenizer.exe` gives me a 404.  Any ideas?

Comment: djones answer highlights that it will by default deny unknown file types. Putting in wwwroot is not enough.