# exe file download not working in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download

I can successfully download an .exe file on localhost.
It does not work when I run the app on Azure.

I tried this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseFileServer(true);

var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles"),
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

This code works fine on localhost.
Deployed as an Azure web app it does not work with .exe files (404 Not Found), even though I can download a .jpg file.

Why can't I download a .exe file?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423744/how-to-allow-powershell-to-download-an-exe-from-a-net-core-mvc-web-app/47425379#47425379

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow powershell to download an EXE from a .net core MVC web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423744/how-to-allow-powershell-to-download-an-exe-from-a-net-core-mvc-web-app)